# Isolated DNS environment: best practice

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns

Can you please share your experience with DNS servers in isolated environment, that provides best performance to clients? I am considering several options, each with their pros and cons...

So, suppose we have an environment with local DNS servers, installed and managed by us (let it be BIND). They are authoritative for all the zones specific to our project. There is no Internet access. There are no private root DNS servers of any kind. There are no external forwarders that would be connected to root servers of any kind.

Our goal is simply to resove project-internal names and never resolve any external names. But in the latter case - avoid causing delays to clients.

What options did I see so far?

1. By default, if I do not configure any forwarders, BIND will recursively query Internet root hints. So if clients query something external, they'll get big delay and then SERVFAIL
2. I can disable recursion (`allow-recursion { none; };`). But then there is a curious side-effect. If you have two nameservers defined on the client, the client will always query both of them. Because if one refuses to do recursion, the client will attempt the other one, hoping that maybe that one will. It gets worse if the other server is temporarily down - it will cause delay until timeout. So effectively, we must have both our nameservers always up to avoid delay. Not so nice HA.
3. I can configure root zone on my DNS servers, making them source of all truth. Sounds like a hack, but maybe that's the right way for isolated environments?
4. Any other proper way...?

P.S. Just to clarify one point here... Why do I even bother with external queries? After all, if some client tries to resolve `google.com`, then it's something wrong on the client, since there is no Internet access anyway. In practice, however, the biggest issue is not with forward queries, but with reverse queries. Many clients try to do some reverse lookups, for some internal IPs. And if those are not defined on my DNS, they will be considered as external queries, so either forwarding or recursion will be attempted by default... seems that the only way out of it is to guarantee that absolutely all internal IP ranges are defined on my DNS as `in-addr.arpa.` zones - which brings me close to the solution 3 above.

I appreciate your expertize on this!

Comment: Option 3 doesn't sound that much like a hack and your DNS servers being source of all truth seems to match your environment. Then again, making yourself authoritative for the complete `in-addr.arpa.` zone should also be fine

Comment: Hmmm I like the idea to create just `in-addr.arpa.`, thank you!

Comment: Can BIND be configured to not have any root hints?  (They're not hard-coded, surely?)

Comment: @HarryJohnston No, not hard-coded - they are in /var/named/named.ca. I can empty that file. But there will be a similar side-effect as in Option 2. BIND will respond with SERVFAIL in this case (i.e. "I must query root hints, but I have none"), so the client will always try the next server in the list.
Looks like the above suggestion from HagenvonEitzen is the most logical: make BIND authoritative for all PTR queries, but keep it non-authoritative for things like "google.com", to avoid some unexpected effect on applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Option 3 doesn't sound that much like a hack and your DNS servers being source of all truth seems to match your environment. Then again, making yourself authoritative for the complete in-addr.arpa. zone should also be fine – Hagen von Eitzen

This answer (from the comments above) sounds the most logical to me. That is, instead of configuring the entire root zone, I can configure just `in-addr.arpa`, making my BIND authoritative only for the reverse queries.